# change substring to upper case

Tags: mysql

I have this query to select part of substring by >.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(translation, '>', 1) FROM categorias
```

What I want is update the substring to the upper case.

However this query has a sintax error

```
UPDATE A.translation
SET A.translation = UPPER(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(A.translation, '>', 1))
FROM categorias as A
```

Any help?

data example:

```
Raw Materials & Chemicals > Rubber & Elastomers
```

that should be updated to

```
RAW MATERIALS & CHEMICALS > Rubber & Elastomers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can remove the inner `SELECT` and you can alter your `UPDATE` syntax slightly to the following:

```
UPDATE categorias
SET translation = UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(translation, '>', 1))
```

Based on your comments I think you want the following:

```
 UPDATE categorias
 SET translation 
  = CONCAT(
          UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(translation, '>', 1)),
          SUBSTRING(translation, INSTR(translation, '>')));
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5635/2)

Comment: I don't know exactly why but I get: /* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0.

Answer (score 2):

`UPDATE` references the table, not the column you are updating, e.g.:

```
UPDATE categorias 
SET translation = UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(translation, '>', 1))
```

Note also, you don't need to use `SELECT` with string functions, they return their results without it.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the exact query you are running.

Comment: Perhaps your table is empty? See an example here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/390ea/2)

Comment: I can run a select like this: `SELECT upper(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A.translationWithPath, '>', 1)) FROM categoriasi18n_new as A`, however `UPDATE categoriasi18n_new as A
SET A.translationWithPath = UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A.translationWithPath, '>', 1))`
doesn't work

Comment: Try: `UPDATE categoriasi18n_new SET translationWithPath = UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(translationWithPath, '>', 1))`

Comment: I still getting:  Affected rows: 0 Found rows: 0 Warnings: 0. thanks

Comment: What is the output of: `select count(*) from categoriasi18n_new` ?